# How correctly use haml template in knockoutjs foreach binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach, haml

I can't get div element ".some" with text "Some" with such haml template and knockout foreach binding. Thus, div element ".steph" forms correctly.

```
.steps{data:{bind: "foreach: steps"}}
  .step
    .steph.editable.act{data:{bind: "text: name"}}
      .some Some
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much do it with `ko.haml` extention by Martin Naumann..

Just call this in your JavaScript

`ko.setTemplateEngine(new ko.hamlEngine());`

and it will allow you to bind knockout attributes to Haml template.

Step by step implementation guide is given on github page.

https://github.com/centralway/ko.haml.js